# Are flat icon and logo design considered inside the same set of skills?

Tags: icon, logo

Currently, I'm looking for designer to help me in designing some flat icons, with such style (flat, minimalist, simple, clean, [like these ones](http://dribbble.com/yccheok)).

Sometimes, I came across some [amazing logo works](http://dribbble.com/ru_ferret) by other designers. I love those works as well.

I was wondering, are "flat icon design" and "logo design" comprised of the same set of skills? If a designer can design an amazingly great logos, can I assume he will be able to design an amazingly great flat icons as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All graphic designers have different strengths and abilities but yes, in general, logo design isn't far removed from icon design so if you find a designer with an aesthetic style you really like, they're likely more than capable.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably include both under the 'digital design' skill set (illustration wouldn't be too far off either).

Both icons and logos require conceptualization, so they are not only technically similar, but the process to get the desired results is also very much alike.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes & no. They can draw, but not invent.

Long answer: Being a logo designer myself, I can say that drawing is not the biggest skill in logo creation. Good logo designers understand the logo history, follow the logo trend, have lots of logo ideas piled up and have design tricks up the sleeve. I assume that, likewise, an icon designer will have distinct experience of their own. Therefore, both will posses the skill to draw the design, but not invent one.

If it's a smaller project, go for the same designer. If it's a large project, split up the work.

Comment: I see what you are getting at, but to say good designers invest in "trends and design tricks" isn't entirely true. The biggest part of good logo design is creative thinking and ability to apply it to business objectives (AKA, problem solving).

Comment: Icon designers also think creatively. I was referring to the logo-specific qualities of creative thinking. :)